# Load-balance via netfilter

Tags: routing, load-balancing, linux-networking

In iptables I can mark some packets(one of four, ie) in preroute and redirect after only marked packets.
Is way to load-balance traffic via netfilter tables?

Answer (score 0):

That will only distribute individual packets to the different back-end servers, not connections, and will hence not work (TCP is stateful).

You should consider using `ipvs` (IP virtual server), see http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/software/ipvs.html (although that site is a bit of a mess). That uses a special module in the kernel to keep track of connections so that you can load balance properly.